# Kubectl create deployment command to deploy a docker image (pulling from dockerhub) throws "Kubectl command not found" error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have created a Kubernetes cluster on GCP and trying to pull the image from docker hub and run it in a container. I am using the following Kubectl command.

```
  sutterhome1976@cloudshell:~ (cohesive-armor-310718)$ Kubectl create deployment hello-world-rest-api --image=in28min/hello-world-rest-api:0.0.1.RELEASE
```

What does that error means? the docker image does very much exist.

```
   -bash: Kubectl: command not found
```

I made sure the image exists on docker hub at
https://hub.docker.com/r/in28min/hello-world-rest-api/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Comment: You appear to have capitalized `kubectl`; Linux is case sensitive

Comment: You are Perfect vision. My bad. Thank you very much. I feel I am a fool.